# Нужно ли настраивать Apache для работы с SSL, если я использую Nginx (proxy) + Apache?

Tags: apache, nginx, ssl

У меня есть сервер с Ubuntu Server 16.04, схема работы веб-сервера стандартная (Apache + mod_php + Nginx как прокси)
Настроил Nginx для работы с установленным SSL сертификатом, надо ли тоже самое проделывать с Apache(имею ввиду настройку Apache для работы с SSL)?

Comment: Нет, не нужно повторно настраивать шифрование

Answer (score 1):

Нет не нужно, если запросы идут только на nginx, а так же nginx и apache находятся на одном сервере.

Если nginx и apache находятся на разных серверах, то настоятельно рекомендуется использовать безопасное соединение.